# ¿como abrir un archivo de excel con pandas y filtrar los datos?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una inquietud acerca de importar un archivo de excel con panda, y es si se puede desde la importación filtrar los datos y asi limitar la cantidad de registros que se cargan en el dataFrame?

Así estoy realizando la importación, y quisiera hacer unos filtros, por los campos finalidad, estado y flujo:

```
df = pd.read_excel(ruta, engine='openpyxl', usecols=['Radicado', 'Identificación', 'Región', 'Centro', 'Finalidad', 'Estado', 'Flujo', 'Estado', 'Responsable', 'Fecha', 'Hora'])
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres filtrar los datos? ¿Te refieres a solo importar esas columnas?

Comment: Hola Fran, solo esas columnas y  de esas columnas por ciertos valores, me explico : el campo finalidad tiene loas opciones ( “normal”, “comercio”, “negocios” ), para este caso solo requiero (comercio”, “negocios”),. Al igual en el campo estado, tiene las opciones (aprobación, rechazo, estudio, verificar ) y solo requiero (estudio y verificar )

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si lo que quieres es operar con esas columnas pues se hace de manera fácil, en cuanto al filtro, depende de lo que quieras hacer

```
df = pd.read_excel(ruta, engine='openpyxl', usecols=['Radicado', 'Identificación', 'Región', 'Centro', 'Finalidad', 'Estado', 'Flujo', 'Estado', 'Responsable', 'Fecha', 'Hora'])

finalidad =df['finalidad']
estado= df['estado']
flujo = df['flujo ']

#filtramos cuando finalidad sea "comercio"
finalidad = df[finalidad == "comercio"]

#imprimimos 
print(finalidad)
```

Esta linea `finalidad = df[finalidad == "comercio"]` es igual que decir `finalidad = df[df["finalidad"] == "comercio"]` pero como la almacenamos en una variable para su mejor manejo, se utilizó de la primera forma.
Esto nos dará como resultado todas las filas que coincidan con el criterio, en este caso cuando el campo `finalidad`  sea igual a `"comercio"`. Si pudieras mostrar tu *Excel* y decir que filtro quieres aplicar te podría ayudar más.
Si tienes alguna duda me la puedes decir

Comment: Hola Christian como estas?
Muchas gracias por la respuesta, perdón sin no me hice entender bien, quisiera saber si estos filtros se pueden hacer desde el importar, es decir, desde  read_excel.  Para no cargar toda la cantidad de registros que tiene el archivo.

Comment: Bueno en mi caso no conozco una fotma de hacer eso, solo se que se puede elegir las columnas con `usecol`, pero aplicar un filtro al leer el Excel, no se. Voy a investigar, si encuentro algo edito mi respuesta

Comment: Encontre una forma, pero regresa un DF con valores boleanos